# I have a workbook with 3 sheets that I want imported in current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following is the code I have worked on so far. Please note that I want each sheet pasted in different worksheets.

```
Sub ImportFileSelecting()

Dim TextFile As Workbook
Dim OpenFiles() As Variant

OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'This options switches off the screenflicker when it is running multiple functions in a single code


Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(1))


'TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy - need to alter this code to copy multiple sheets from current workbook

TextFile.Sheets.Copy

Workbooks(1).Activate

'ActiveSheet.Paste - alter this code to open multiple sheets to paste data

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
'This command closes theclipboard window (about keeping the date in the clipboard)
                
TextFile.Close

MsgBox "File imported. Proceed to Step 5"

End Sub
```

The code isn't working. I am assuming it's "Activesheet.Paste" because only 1 sheet was active in the current workbook. I am a bit unsure about copy as well. I am a beginner when it comes to vba.

Comment: Add a new sheet, activate it, and then do the paste. You should be able to find existing questions here that demonstrate how to add that sheet.

Comment: Also, *The code isn't working* is an absolutely useless, vague and meaningless problem description. If you want people here to be able to help you, you need to be **specific**. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. I'd suggest special attention to [ask] and [mre].